# How can I connect a google sandbox checkout to test in-app purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, sandbox, google-checkout

I am wondering if it is possible  (and if so how) to use Google Checkout Merchant Sandbox for the android in-app purchases, for testing. 
I know that what happens now is that even test accounts are charged for the test purchases.
I also know that there are 4 purchase codes that don't actually charge the credit card but they are not really useful for real world testing.
So the only option left is to maybe somehow use the merchant sandbox if it is possible.

So I ask again is it possible to use the google sandbox accounts to test inapp purchases and if so how would that work using googles own api system.

Comment: I am **not** an android dev (yet) - I don't think it will work because "standard" Google Checkout has it's own merchant numbers, etc. It does not share it with other Payment APIs. e.g. Wallet for Digital (which has sellerid).

Comment: OK thanks, Maybe you should change that to answer so i can accept it.